# Calling native methods in JS when they are overloaded

Tags: javascript, cloudflare

So basically the issue I am having, is I am working on a simple little JS library for a website, and have run into a bit of an issue. 
The website is hosted on cloudflare which uses rocket-optimizer. Now my code creates a script element, and the script it loads then should make calls to a server for constant pings, and in the process the server logs various information. This library is working find in other environments, but the rocket-optimizer is killing it.

```
var dd = document, ll = dd.createElement('script'), ss = dd.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
ll.type = 'text/javascript'; ll.async = true;               
ll.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + serverDomain + "/alive?" + params;
ss.parentNode.insertBefore(ll, ss);
```

Now the problem I am having is quite simple really, the rocket.js library has from what I can tell, overloaded document.createElement with its own neat function, which in the event of script tags, gives a "close" copy of the conventional script tag, though it defines a setter/getter for the src property. What the setter does is rather then setting src it puts it into the data-rocketsrc which I have determined then is handled by the rocket-optimizer which passes this back to the pages server, which then does all the calls to my server, passing back the result.

This causes what I'm tracking and doing to completely go out the window for various off topic reasons.

Now I've been trying to find ways to get the original createElement back in the picture, the issue is though since rocket.js is loaded first, and for the moment it appears I have no way to get my script to have priority, I'm kind of stumped with how I can correct this. The thought to possibly redo my own createElement method is a thought, but something I would rather avoid since it adds to what I'm sending and it seems like its something I shouldn't have to send.

Any thoughts and assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are some function that simply cannot be reused if it's pointer is lost (function is replaced with `null` or variable that contains function is inside private scope, so you cannot access it). If `rocket.js` saved `document.createElement` function to private scope, it simply cannot be reused. You need to inspect `rocket.js` code. If you find something like this

```
document.createElement = (function(a){
    // Some other code....
    return function(b){
        return a(b);
    };
})(document.createElement);
```

then you cannot get native function back. Although, you can try `document.__proto__.createElement`, which may not be overriden.

Comment: You can override `document.createElement` inside chrome, I would suspect you can do it for most browsers as well.

Comment: I agree with Ben, it can be done, since when I use the developer tools on chrome, and try to step into the createElement function, it jumps straight to rocket.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Document` object's prototype to find the original function, and assign it to a different name on the object.

```
document.$createElement = Document.prototype.createElement;

document.$createElement('div'); //The original function
document.createElement('div'); //The library's overridden function
```

Note `Document` and `document` are different objects.

Comment: Brilliant Answer, completely didn't think of the prototype and should be compatible with most browsers so it should solve majority of the issues, thank you :)